# Fast Report for Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5, fastreport

Is it possible to have a master detail report in firemonkey using the fast report component. I am using Fast Report 4 (embarcadero edition) with Delphi XE5.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to buy Fast Reports FMX edition to use Fast Reports in the front end of a Fire Monkey application.

There is a workaround which might be suitable for your requirements, as detailed in this Embarcadero Developer Network article :- [Here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42391)

Comment: I've Fast report's Embarcadero edition. Isn't is possible with that.